# Adding new input:checkbox and not has value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have problem in add new `input:checkbox`, when i adding new input and checked on it next setup clicked on button i not have value for `input:checkbox` that was checked. how is fix it?

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/G4QRp/

```
$(function () {
    $('a.add_input').live('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $class = '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class').split(" ")[0];
        var size_un = $($class).length;
        var $this = $(this),
            $div = $this.closest($class),
            $clone = $div.clone().hide().insertAfter($div).fadeIn('slow');
        $clone.find('.adda').not(':has(.remove_input)').append('<div class="mediumCell"><a href="" class="remove_input"></a></div>');
        $clone.find('input').val('').prop('checked', false);
        $this.remove();
        var size_un = $($class).length---1;
        $($class + ':last input:checkbox').prop('name', 'checkbox_units[' + size_un + '][]');
        console.log($($class + ':last input:checkbox').prop('name'));
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm still not clear on what the expected behaviour is.

Comment: Could you simplify the code to pinpoint the actual problem?

Comment: If you have problem explaining the problem in English, try accompanying your text with a screenshot of how you want the check-boxes to be like

Comment: `var size_un = $($class).length---1;` might be the problem. I don't know how the interpreter is supposed to parse that, but `length---1` raises `RangeError` on Firefox 6.

Comment: see this:http://jsfiddle.net/G4QRp/2/ problem not of `size_un`. i mean is that, you when add new input and check(select) on checkbox(in new input) and next click on button `Click me`, you not getting value from checkbox that clicked, why?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/G4QRp/2/ in Chrome (14.0) and IE 8, and it seems to work fine. I am always getting value of a checkbox and have tried up to 5 new rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code always clears the value of all the checkboxes it adds:

```
    $clone.find('input').val('').prop('checked', false);
```

It's working fine, though it's quite confusing.  The alert correctly shows the checkboxes that are checked, but since your code has set the value to '' for each of them, well, it's empty. If you change it like this:

```
    $clone.find('input').prop('checked', false);
```

it shows the values to be the same as the original checkboxes.

You might want to think about using "data-" attributes instead of the "class" string for storing things like that "add_units" class name.